# Regex: Select the First Closest Exact Match Until the End

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

**Objective**: to extract the first email from an email thread

**Description**: Based on manual inspection of the emails, I realized that the next email in the email thread always starts with a set of From, Sent, To and Subject

**Test Input**:

```
Hello World from: the other side of the first email

from: this
sent: at
to: that
subject: what

second email

from: this
sent: at
to: that
subject: what


third email

from: this
date: at
to: that
subject: what

fourth email
```

**Expected output**:

```
Hello World from: the other side of the first email
```

**Failed Attempts**:

Following breaks when there's a `from:` in the first email

`(.*)((from:[\s\S]+?)(sent:[\s\S]+?)(to:[\s\S]+?)(subject:[\s\S]+))`

Following fails when there are repeated groups of From, Sent, To and Subject

`([\s\S]+)((from:(?:(?!from:)[\s\S])+?sent:(?:(?!sent:)[\s\S])+?to:(?:(?!to:)[\s\S])+?subject:(?:(?!subject:)[\s\S])+))`

The second attempt [works with PCRE(PHP)](https://regex101.com/r/dw05sx/5) when an ungreedy option (flag) is selected. However, this option is not available in python and I couldn't figure out a way to make it work.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dw05sx/4)

Comment: I am sorry, but I am missing the point here.

Comment: Are you just trying to extract `Hello World from: the other side of the first email` from shown input?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It is assumed to be the first email in the entire mail chain that needs to be extracted based on the suggested approach of looking for the group of from, sent, to and subject.

Comment: Will this work for you? https://regex101.com/r/dw05sx/6

Comment: You could use a capturing group `^(.*)\r?\n\s*\r?\nfrom:.*\r?\nsent:.*\r?\nto:.*\r?\nsubject:.*` See https://regex101.com/r/fLbKb4/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird do you wanna put that as an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only get the first match, you could use a capturing group and match exactly what should follow.

```
^(.*)\r?\n\s*\r?\nfrom:.*\r?\nsent:.*\r?\nto:.*\r?\nsubject:
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(.*)` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `\r?\n\s*` Match a newline followed by 0+ times a whitespace char using `\s*`
- `\r?\nfrom:.*` Match the next line starting with `from:`
- `\r?\nsent:.*` Match the next line starting with `sent:`
- `\r?\nto:.*` Match the next line starting with `to:`
- `\r?\nsubject:.*` Match the next line starting with `subject:`

Note that in the demo link the global flag `g` at the right top is not enabled.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v09eBp/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/iEdbqO)

If the first line can span multiple lines and if it acceptable to note cross any of the lines that start with `from:`,  `sent:`, `to:` or `subject:` you could also use a negative lookahead.

```
^(.*(?:\r?\n(?!(?:from|sent|to|subject):).*)*)\r?\n\s*\r?\nfrom:.*\r?\nsent:.*\r?\nto:.*\r?\nsubject:
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p33Sde/1)

If there are spaces between `from`, `sent`, `to` and `subject` 0+ (`*`) whitespace characters can be matched

```
^(.*(?:\r?\n(?!(?:from|sent|to|subject):).*)*)\r?\s*\r?\sfrom:.*\r?\s*sent:.*\r?\s*to:.*\r?\s*subject:
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p33Sde/2)

Comment: What if the email text is more than one line long? Shouldn't you use *re.DOTALL*?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Good point, you can use `re.DOTALL` but to limit unnecessary backtracking you could also use a negative lookahead. I have added it as a second pattern.

Comment: Although this is an acceptable answer for the sample input text in the question, it fails as soon as there's a new line entered after the from or any of those group words. I tried using single line flag (re.DOTALL) but it breaks the regex

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati In that case one option is to match 0+ whitespace chars after https://regex101.com/r/1LsrcT/1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but why don't you just do this:

```
re.compile(r"^.*from:\s(\w+@\w+\.\w+)")
```

This will find the first string in "email-form" (group 1) after the first "from: " at beginning of the string.

Comment: This could potentially work, but here the requirement is to specifically match only when there is a group of from, sent, to and subject

Comment: Is there the possibility of that not being the case though? It seems to me this data is highly structured. What other strings would you expect there to exist to fortify your regex against?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = """Hello World from: the other side of the first email

from: this
sent: at
to: that
subject: what

second email

from: this
sent: at
to: that
subject: what


third email

from: this
date: at
to: that
subject: what

fourth email"""

m = re.match(r'.*?(?=^from:[^\n]*\nsent:[^\n]*\nto:[^\n]*\nsubject:[^\n]*$)', text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
print(m.group(0))
```

Prints:

```
Hello World from: the other side of the first email
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, each email message has a `Message-id:` header that uniquely identifies that message.  Messages grouped in a thread make a tree of messages, al based on the header `In-response-to:` header, that links children (responses) with parents.

Your assumption can be used to link messages that lack the `Message-id:` header or the ones that lack `In-Response-to:` header, but that's infrequent, difficult to correlate and error prone.  RFC-822 compliant messages can be authored by a different person than the one they are sent on behalf (fields `From:`,  `Sender:`, `Resent-from:`, `Resent-Sender:`, etc.)  A thorough reading of [RFC-2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) is suggested, in order to know how to manage or archive internet mail messages.

The `Message-id:` and `In-Response-To:` headers are in the RFC-822 definition of an internet message format, and have been conserved in the later updates to those RFCs.  It is the right way to proceed to group messages and answers.  It has been included also in the update done in RFC-2822, so the use of those headers should sound mandatory to link messages in conversation threads.  It is used also in NNTP (news) messages, and almmost any mail reader uses them.